# How to apply multiple filters on one image in opencv?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm trying to use `opencv` to do gabor filter on my image, and I know I should use multiple params and apply several filters, but I have no idea how to apply all these things in one image, can I just use the `opencv` methd `cvAddWeighted`? or there is some other way? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to apply several filters, you can just 'chain' them (apply one after the other):

```
Mat img;
Mat kernel1 = getGaborKernel(...);
Mat kernel2 = getGaborKernel(...);
Mat kernel3 = getGaborKernel(...);
Mat kernel4 = getGaborKernel(...);


cv::filter2D(img, img, CV_32F, kernel1);
cv::filter2D(img, img, CV_32F, kernel2);
cv::filter2D(img, img, CV_32F, kernel3);
cv::filter2D(img, img, CV_32F, kernel4);
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has `gabor filter` in its Image Processing module. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973983/how-to-get-gabor-feature-using-opencv), you can simply get the gabor kernel and apply it on the image. The code from the link

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

cv::Mat kernel = cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);
Mat src_f; // img converted to float 
Mat dest;
cv::filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);
```

You can implement your own `Gabor filter`. It creates one filter and applies it on the image. [Github Repo Link](https://github.com/dominiklessel/opencv-gabor-filter)